# include files, typedefs and forward decl

Tags: c++, header-files

I have a C++ thread wrapper class around win32/pthreads. The problem is in my header I need alot of the biggie-include like windows.h and boost::function, for declaring my typedefs below.

Is there any way around this? I know you can forward declare classes and structs, but datatypes like the win32 HANDLE and templated functions in a namespace...?

```
    #include "boost/function.hpp"

    /* Thread wrapper class */
    class IThread
    {
    public:
        #if defined _WIN32 || _WIN64
            #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
            #include <Windows.h>
            #undef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
            typedef HANDLE ThreadHandle;  
        #else
            #include <pthread.h>
            typedef pthread_t ThreadHandle;
        #endif

        enum ThreadState
        {
            DETACHED = 0,
            RUNNING,
            FINISHED
        };

        typedef boost::function1<void, void*> Task;

        virtual ~IThread() { }

        IThread& operator=(IThread& other);
        virtual int32_t Join() = 0;
        virtual int32_t SetPriority(int32_t priority) = 0;

        virtual ThreadHandle& GetNativeHandle() = 0;
        virtual ThreadState GetThreadState() const = 0;

    };
```

Thanks

Comment: A `HANDLE` is just a `void *`. Just say `typedef void * ThreadHandle;` For the WINAPI data types, you can find my sources [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Can't you move the typedef outside your class?

Comment: Why should they be outside the class? Dosn't it make more sense to have the handle declared as part of the class?

Comment: Absurd question of the day: Why do you want to roll your own thread library wrapper? If you are already using `boost::function`, just use `boost::thread` which is close to what `std::thread` is in C++11. Multithreading is a hard domain, I would avoid the adapter and just focus on the application, which is probably complex enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume this isn't your real code because I can't see how includes could work in the middle of your class definition.

In this case you probably want to not expose the native thread identifier at all. Instead, provide abstract capabilities to act on threads in a sane manner and at no time expose the implementation details such as `HANDLE`. Then you can move the includes to your source file and problem averted.

Also note that doing the `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` + `#include <Windows.h>` in a header file means that someone that doesn't WANT `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` but includes your header before their own `windows.h` include will get the lean-and-mean unexpectedly.

EDIT: I think it's fine to use `boost::function` in the header because the include is always the same regardless of environment. As long as you always expose it as `Task` instead of as the `function` itself it can be considered part of the interface.